# SQL: Get top users that follow same users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table `followers` that looks like this:

```
id    |follower_id|followee_id|
1     |     1     |     2     |
2     |     1     |     3     |
2     |     1     |     4     |
3     |     2     |     3     |
4     |     2     |     4     |
5     |     3     |     2     |
6     |     4     |     6     |
```

Where `follower` is a user_id and `followee` is the user they follow.

How can I find the users that have the most common followees with let's say user `1`?

The results need to be ordered by number of common followees.

For example for the current table the results for user `1` would be:

```
follower_id|common_followees|
2          |        2       |
3          |        1       |
```

As you can see `4` does not appear in results since it has no common followees with user `1`

I hope I explained the problem right.

Thank You.

Comment: why isn't `follower_id = 4` and `common_followees = 1` not coming in your result set for user `1`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Because `4` and `1` don't have common followees.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! You could edit your question further to explain, as it is bit unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-join and aggregation:

```
select f.follower_id, count(*) as num_common_followees
from followers f join
     followers f1
     on f.followees = f1.followees and f1.follower_id = 1
group by f.follower_id;
```

You can add `where f.follower_id <> 1`.  I like to leave that row in as a validation check.